# Function parameters evaluation order: is it UB if we pass reference?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

This is undefined behavior:

```
void feedMeValue(int x, int a) {
  cout << x << " " << a << endl;
}
int main() {
  int a = 2;
  int &ra = a;
  feedMeValue(ra = 3, a); // equivalent to: feedMeValue(a = 3, a) (see note bellow)
  return 0;
}
```

because depending on what parameter gets evaluated first we could call `(3, 2)` or `(3, 3)`.

However this:

```
void feedMeReference(int x, int const &ref) {
  cout << x << " " << ref << endl;
}

int main() {
  int a = 2;
  int &ra = a;
  feedMeReference(ra = 3, a); // equivalent to: feedMeReference(a = 3, a) (see note bellow)
  return 0;
}
```

will always output `3 3` since the second parameter is a reference and all parameters have been evaluated before the function call, so even if the second parameter is evaluated before of after `ra  = 3`, the function received a reference to `a` which will have a value of `2` or `3` at the time of the evaluation, but will always have the value `3` at the time of the function call.

Is the second example UB? It is important to know because the compiler is free to do anything if it detects undefined behavior, even if I know it would always yield the same results.

---

Note: I will leave `feedMeReference(ra = 3, a)` as some answers reference `ra` but you should note that a **simpler equivalent** problem to this is if we call `feedMeReference(a = 3, a)` (simpler because we eliminate `ra` which is just in the way of our issue (the second parameter being a reference)).

Comment: As your compiler is a he I imagine it will opt for maximum irrationality.

Comment: @Bathsheba yeah, I do tend to personificate the compiler.

Comment: removed the `ra` local reference, because I don't think it makes a difference and the emphasis is on the second paramater being a ref or not

Comment: I've rolled back as your edit invalidated the answer.

Comment: @Bathsheba ok, I thought it is the same thing, so sorry. Could you tell me how does it changes the answer?

Comment: @Bathsheba "invalidated the answer" -- how so?

Comment: @n.m. JK refers to `ra` which was removed in the edit.

Comment: Are you seriously considering writing such code, or is it just out of interest?

Comment: It actually came up in a larger unit test code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's an interesting question.  In your first case, there is
undefined behavior because an object is modified and also
accessed without an intervening sequence point (in the language
of C++03---C++11 used different language to say essentially the
same thing).  In the second, there is no undefined behavior,
because initializing a reference with an lvalue doesn't access
the object, so the only access is `ra = 3`.  (Calling the
function establishes a sequence point, so accesses in the
function have a sequence point between them and the `ra = 3`.)

Comment: can you tell me if instead of `(ra=3, a)` we have `(a=3, a)` we have the exact same thing?

Comment: @bolov, yes, it is the same, since `ra` is just an alias to `a`